# "No module named time"

Tags: python, pip, python-2.6

I compiled Python from source using:

```
wget http://python.org/ftp/python/2.6.6/Python-2.6.6.tar.bz2 
tar jxvf Python-2.6.6.tar.bz2 
cd Python-2.6.6 
./configure 
make            
make install
```

Version of Python:

```
as3:~# python -V
Python 2.6.6
```

I also installed pip installer but when I use `pip install xxx`, I always get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/distribute-0.6.49-py2.6.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 16, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, re, imp, types, zipfile, zipimport
ImportError: No module named time
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you run `make clean` (cleans the built files) and then rerun `make` and add the output in the post?

I suspect this is because Python's import search path is broken; add the output of python -c "import sys;print(sys.path)".

Answer (score 1):

You need to save all the output generated by `configure` in a file and check whether it tried to build the `time` module and if not, then why not.

Usually, this doesn't happen because of missing header files. Fix these problems and build Python again.

If you have a package manager, then you should really consider installing Python from there: It will then come with all the dependencies and all available modules should just work.

Lastly, make sure you execute the correct executable. To check this, run Python with an absolute path. To execute it in the current folder, use `$PWD/python`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't apt-get remove python.  I suggest installing it from the repo again, and if needed, build a 2nd python under /usr/local.

Answer (score -2):

i solved it as follows:

```
cd cd Python-2.6.6 
make uninstall
cd ~
rm -rf Python-2.6.6.tar.bz2 Python-2.6.6
```

let's compile sqlite3 first.

```
wget http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-amalgamation-3.6.20.tar.gz
tar zxvf  sqlite-amalgamation-3.6.20.tar.gz
cd  sqlite-3.5.6
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/lib/sqlite3
make
make install  
rm /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/python
```

then compile python2.7:

```
wget http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.6/Python-2.7.6.tar.bz2
tar jxvf  Python-2.7.6.tar.bz2
cd  Python-2.7.6
nano setup.py
```

( add '/usr/local/lib/sqlite3/include', to the paragraph below:

```
sqlite_inc_paths = [ '/usr/include',
                         '/usr/include/sqlite',
                         '/usr/include/sqlite3',
                         '/usr/local/include',
                         '/usr/local/include/sqlite',
                         '/usr/local/include/sqlite3',
                         '/usr/local/lib/sqlite3/include',
```

```
./configure
make
make install
```

```
as3:~/Python-2.7.6# python -V
Python 2.7.6
as3:~/Python-2.7.6# python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 20 2013, 07:15:04)
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3
>>>               (no “ImportError: No module named _sqlite3” appears)
```

thus i solved the 2 errors:“ImportError: No module named _sqlite3” and 
“ImportError: No module named time”